# Unable to get Rsyslog structured data in syslog messages

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I am trying to log messages with structured data . But it is showing null value for structured data. I am working with rsyslog 8.9.0.Can someone tell me either i need to load some module or modify source to get structure data SD-IDs in logged message.??

Template:

```
<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP:::daterfc3339%%HOSTNAME%%syslogtag%%APPNAME%%PROCID%%MSGID% %msg% %STRUCTURED-DATA%\n
```

getting message format as below:

```
<142>  2015-01-29T06:43:53.081641-05:00 localhost login[2116]: login 2116 -  [2116 : 2116 INFO]SERIAL Login from IP:127.0.0.1 user:admin -
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when structured-data has not been assigned a value or is empty. Please move usage of your template that uses structured data in rsyslog.config to be after structured-data has been assigned.